# Ruby : Datamapper don't insert in database

Tags: ruby, insert, datamapper

I a have the following datamapper ressource :

```
class Job
  include DataMapper::Resource
  storage_names[:default] = 'job'
  property :id,         Serial
  property :at,         Integer,  :required => true,  :min => 0
  property :name,       Float,    :required => true,  :default => 0
  property :cpu,        Float,    :required => true,  :default => 0
  property :memory,     Float,    :required => true,  :default => 0
end
```

When do :

```
DataMapper.auto_migrate!
```

The table 'job' is correctly created in the database.
But when I do :

```
  Job.create(
    :at      => entry[:timestamp],
    :name    => process.to_s,
    :cpu     => data[0],
    :memory  => data[1]
  )
```

Nothing is really inserted in the 'job' database table.
(Nothing in datamapper log too)

Any idea ?

Comment: From [datamapper documentation](http://datamapper.org/docs/create_and_destroy.html) you can ask Datamapper to raise exceptions on error: `Job.raise_on_save_failure = true`

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling dm-validations and checking `#errors` in the returned object, this will tell you if there are any problems with the data. If its invalid, DataMapper won't insert anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Job.save` after your `Job.Create` :)

Answer (score 0):

The error was :

```
property :name,       Float,    :required => true,  :default => 0
```

and

```
:name    => process.to_s,
```

float <-> String

thats why datamapper don't insert the object database.

Thanks all for your helps.